# Jest testing module not found

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I'm testing my js app with [jest](https://jestjs.io/). In my package.json I map all the modules like 
described in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string):

```
 "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@db/(.*)": "<rootDir>/db/$1",
      "@src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
      "@dto/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/dto/$1",
      "@repos/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/repos/$1",
      "@fetchers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/fetchers/$1",
      "@controllers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/controllers/$1",
      "@parsers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/parsers/$1",
      "@streams/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/streams/$1",
      "@validators/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/validators/$1"
    }
  },
```

However when I instantiate a new RestRepo that contains an import at the top, I get this error when I execute the test:

```
Cannot find module '@db' from 'RestRepo.js'

Require stack:
  src/repos/RestRepo.js
  tests/unit/RestEndpoint.test.js

> 1 | const { RestEndpoint } = require('@db');
    |                          ^
  2 | 
  3 | class RestRepo {
```

How can I fix this and why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing

```
"@db/(.*)": "<rootDir>/db/$1",
```

with

```
"@db(.*)": "<rootDir>/db$1",
```

this way the capturing group will match an optional slash `/` if present and

```
require("@db")
```

will be interpreted as

```
require("<rootDir>/db");
```

---

**Or** just add another entry

```
"@db": "<rootDir>/db",
```